# Weird Buttonset behavior

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have:

```
<div id="wid_weekdays">
    <input type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" checked="true" id="weekday1">
    <label for="weekday1">MO</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" checked="true" id="weekday2">
     <label for="weekday2">TU</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" checked="true" id="weekday3">
     <label for="weekday3">WE</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" checked="true" id="weekday4">
     <label for="weekday4">TH</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" checked="true" id="weekday5">
     <label for="weekday5">FR</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" checked="true" id="weekday6">
     <label for="weekday6">SA</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" checked="true" id="weekday7">
     <label for="weekday7">SU</label>
</div>
```

and

```
$(function(){ $("#wid_weekdays").buttonset(); });
```

Mixed with a load of more code, which somehow causes:

[image]

Libraries,stylesheets,etc:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery-ui/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui/plugins/globalize.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui/plugins/mousewheel.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui/plugins/shortcut.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jqGrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script src="js/nav.js"></script>
```

HTML:
http://pastebin.com/kNSDi8PW
CSS: http://pastebin.com/dF2WLdDP
If I paste this code into an empty file with nothing else on it, it works properly.
What can be causing this? And how can I fix that?

Comment: where is the corrosponding css?

Comment: Create a fiddle and this will be simple to resolve, otherwise it's impossible to diagnose what the offending code is, as it hasn't been included within your question.

Comment: I can't simply create a fiddle. This is for a huge project with zillions of lines of  code.

Comment: then paste only the relevant of your zillions (1500) of lines of code

Comment: Regarding your edit: I belive you won't come around posting your entire html page somehow somewhere. Its just digging in the dark without..

Comment: Posted HTML in the question

Comment: that doesn't help a lot. Please post your entire working page somewhere where we can view it live. If you can't for what reason ever, try using firefox's firebug and inspect those checkboxes/labels. Play around in firebug with the css options and you'll find out what causes the linebreak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#wid_weekdays label, #wid_weekdays input 
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

There will be most likely an enforcement of a linebreak, a `display: block;` or something like this. Please post your CSS and/or create a jsfiddle so that we can be sure.

regarding your comments:

```
#wid_weekdays label, #wid_weekdays input {
    display: inline; }

<input type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" checked="true" id="weekday7">
<label for="weekday7">SU</label>
```

all labels and inputs that are a children of #wid_weekdays will be displayed as inline now.

Comment: So its the desired result you have? If you don't want your labels to break there, create a new class and asign it to these specific buttons.

Comment: What CSS would prevent this behavior?

Comment: so the situation seems to be more complex.. as the other commenters in your post already told you: create a JS fiddle. Take the resulting HTML code that shows the faulsy behavior, reduce your code to that part and create a jsfiddle out of it.

Comment: If I do that, everything seems to work properly. JSFiddle shows the correct results.

Comment: Are you using an old library on your local machine?

Comment: I'm posting all libraries I'm using in the question.

Comment: I posted everything that seemed relevant.